# Attach file in mail using Codeigniter & PHPMailer

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer and codeigniter

https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer to send mail with attach file but I got error my code is

```
$this->load->library('email');
$result = $this->email
                ->from('xxxx@gmail.com',"xxx xxx")
                ->reply_to('xxx@xxx.com')    // Optional, an account where a human being reads.
                ->to('xxx@xxx.com')
                ->subject($subject)
                ->message($body)
                ->AddAttachment('/var/www/html/phase2.png', 'test.png')
                ->send();
```

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method MY_Email::AddAttachment()**

Comment: Use `$this->email->attach('/var/www/html/phase2.png');
$this->email->attach('test.png');` to attach file

Comment: not working for me

Comment: no attachment in mail, i am doing any this wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In **Codeigniter we use `attach()` instead of `AddAttachment()`**. And what ever the **file you attaching place it inside Codeigniter project folder**.(**outside application** folder).

Try this

```
$this->email->from('xxxx@gmail.com',"xxx xxx");
$this->email->reply_to('xxx@xxx.com');
$this->email->to('xxx@xxx.com');
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($body);
$this->email->attach('assets/mail/phase2.png');

if(!$this->email->send()){
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
else{
    echo "Success";
}
```

So your file structure looks like

```
application
assets
    - images
    - css
    - js
    - mail
        - phase2.png
system
index.php
.htaccess
```

Read this links

1. [`attach($filename[, $disposition = ''[, $newname = NULL[, $mime = '']]])`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html?highlight=email#CI_Email::attach)

Comment: I got message "You must provide at least one recipient email address." and also getting mail without any attachment

Comment: `$this->email->to` should filed. and try once

Comment: still get same error but just received email without atachment

Comment: make sure image is attached or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107044/discussion-between-vipin-sharma-and-abdulla).

Answer (score 0):

On github I found that the method needed to attach a file is not AddAttachment, but attach.

https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer/blob/master/libraries/MY_Email.php#L416

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` like:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/beta/uploads/file.pdf");
```